# Read file input and convert the line read into an array

Tags: bash, string, array

I have the following code: `Text read from file: "E" "01" "Adv - Initial" "07/11/2017"`

And I would like it be stored in an array like below:

`array[0] = "E"
array[1] = "01"
array[2] = "Adv - Initial"
array[3] = "07/11/2017"`

I have tried:
`itemData=( "$line" )` in a while loop. But I don't get the results I want.

Comment: Is `Text read from file: ` part of the file, or part of the instructions? Are there multiple lines to loop over (why else were you looping?).

Comment: You might want to investigate the bash [`mapfile` command](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-mapfile)

Answer (score 1):

One of the problems is `"Adv - Initial"` will be broken in `Adv`, `-`, and `Initial`. Need to play with changing `IFS`.

```
#/bin/bash

savIFS=$IFS
IFS=\"
array=($line)
IFS=$savIFS

echo "${array[1]}"
echo "${array[3]}"
echo "${array[5]}"
echo "${array[7]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to *append* your current array. To achieve this do

```
declare -a array
```

to declare your array and

```
array+=("$line")
```

to append an element to your array.

[Bash Reference Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameters):

> In the context where an assignment statement is assigning a value to a shell variable or array index (see Arrays), the ‘+=’ operator can be used to append to or add to the variable's previous value.